# Change colorspace of external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, color

I have an external monitor LG 27GL850 which displays greenish colors when connected to MacBook Pro 2016.

I had a similar problem when I connected the monitor to other devices, but the problem was easily solved by changing the colorspace of the monitor from RGB to YCbCr444.

The problem is, that I can't find a way to change the color space of the monitor in the "System Preferences"

Is it possible to change the color space of the external monitor? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm using a USB-C to DisplayPort cable

Comment: Have you looked at what profiles are available to you in System Prefs > Displays > Colour? If you can't find a good one in there, you can manually calibrate it. Hold Opt when clicking Calibrate… to get more detailed settings.

Comment: @Tetsujin I checked the settings and there are no good profiles. I tried the calibration with option button, but I can't find the option to select the color space

Comment: The very act of calibrating is what sets the colour space. You're looking for a theoretical solution which isn't the correct way to deal with calibration & colour profiling. This is what's known as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @Tetsujin I solved the same problem in Windows and Linux opperating systems. The only thing that I had to do is change the color space.

Comment: The Mac has colour management that makes both Windows & nix look like 1984. You could have done it by now. See this if you want to force a non-native colour space instead - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/08/24/macbook-pro-external-monitor-display-problem/